# JQuery in C# Winform crashes

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, winforms, jquery-ui

I have a Winforms application written in C#. In the Winform is just a Webbrowser control which shows a simple html page.

The page looks as follows

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#selectStores").selectmenu();
        });    
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="demo">
    <div class="login-content">
            <div class="username">

                    <div class="input-field">
                        <input type="hidden" class="inputfield" id="store" name="store">
                        <input type="text" class="inputfield" name="name" id="name">
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="password">

                    <div class="input-field">
                        <input type="text" class="inputfield" name="password">
                    </div>
                    <div id="chooseStoreLocation">
                        <select id="selectStores"> 
                            <option>20000</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="password">                       
                    <div class="login-button">                            
                        <input class="button-short" type ="submit">
                    </div>
            </div>               
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that I get an error message when I start the app.
The error seems to occour here  `$("#selectStores").selectmenu();`

The error just states that an error is occured in column 0 row 0 in http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js

My question is why does it work within the chrome and normal IE but won't work withing my webbrowser control and is there a way to fix it ?

**EDIT**:

I tried the website from where I got the example ( https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render ) in my webbrowser control and it worked like charm . So it should work correctly but I am doing something wrong

Comment: just a guess but your jquery version is quiet old, did you try the same with an actual version?

Comment: I will give it a try

Comment: The newer version (jquery2.x) doesn't support IE 6,7,8 . The C# webbrowser control is an IE control and I guess it uses one of the above mentioned versions of it